# Parse complex date format

Tags: java, date

I'm a beginner in java programmeing.

I want to parse a complex date format : `YYYY-MM-DDthh:mm:ssTZD`, for example `2014-09-24T21:32:39-04:00`

**I tried this :**

```
String str_date="2014-09-24T21:32:39-04:00";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DDthh:mm:ss");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);
```

But for the timezone part `(-04:00)`, i have no idea what to put `(after the :ss)`

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Java < 7` then you'd need to remove `':'` from your input and parse it:

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String str_date="2014-09-24T21:32:39-04:00";
        str_date = str_date.replaceAll(":(\\d\\d)$", "$1");
        System.out.println("Input modified according to Java 6: "+str_date);
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
```

prints:

```
Input modified according to Java 6: 2014-09-24T21:32:39-0400
Wed Sep 24 21:32:39 EDT 2014
```

Answer (score 2):

**Java7**

[`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation lists the timezone as `z`, `Z`, and `X` and for you it looks like you want `XXX`.

**Java6**

Java7 added `X` specifier, but 6 still has the `Z` and `z`. However, you will have to modify the string first so that it either has no colon in the timezone or has `GMT` before the `-`:

```
String str_date="2014-09-24T21:32:39-04:00";
int index = str_date.lastIndexOf( '-' );

str_date = str_date.substring( 0, index ) + "GMT" + str_date.substring( index+1 );
```

Then you can use the format specifier `z`

Comment: I got an exception with this message "Illegal pattern character 'X'" !

Comment: @user You're using an older version of Java.

Comment: Yes i'm using java 6, any alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

## ISO 8601

Your string complies with the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. That standard is used as the default in parsing and generating strings by two excellent date-time libraries:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- java.time package (bundled with Java 8, inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310)

Merely pass your string to the constructor or factory method. A built-in formatter is automatically used to parse your string.

Unlike java.util.Date, in these two libraries a date-time object knows its own assigned time zone. The offset from UTC specified at the end of your string is used to calculate a number of milliseconds (or nanoseconds in java.time) since the Unix epoch of the beginning of 1970 in UTC time zone. After that calculation, the resulting date-time is assigned a time zone of your choice. In this example I arbitrarily assign a India time zone. For clarity this example creates a second date-time object in UTC.

## Joda-Time

```
DateTimeZone timeZoneIndia = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ); 
DateTime dateTimeIndia = new DateTime( "2014-09-24T21:32:39-04:00" , timeZoneIndia );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeIndia.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```